# Implementing meaningful equals method for non-static inner classes

Tags: java, inner-classes, equality

I am currently wondering if there is a good way of implementing an `equals` method for a non-static inner class in Java. I basically a class `Foo` with an inner-class `Bar` like this:

```
public class Foo {

  private final String foo; // constructor omitted

  public /* non-static */ class Bar {

    private final String bar; // constructor omitted

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return other != null && other.getClass() == getClass()
        && ((Bar) other).bar.equals(this.bar)
        && Foo.this.equals(Foo.((Bar) other)); // Will, of course, not compile.
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other != null && other.getClass() == getClass()
      && ((Foo) other).foo.equals(foo);
  }
}
```

My classes are a lot more complex in reality and I want to reuse the `Foo#equals` method from within `Bar#equals` in order to save me a lot of code. I am now considering to make the "inner-class-relationship" explicit in order to being able to refer to the "outer" class. However, then I have to add accessor methods manually and I want to avoid this. I cannot get rid of the feeling that there should be a Java approach of doing this.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the string field `bar` to `Bar`?

Comment: Is the intention to have the same exact logic in the `Bar` class's `equals()` method as in `Foo`'s?

Comment: you should compare objects with `equals()` not `==`

Comment: @KlemensMorbe when comparing classes, it's the same thing.

Comment: " Iwant to reuse theFoo#equals method from withinBar#equals" - I don't see why you would want to do this for an inner class.

Comment: I'm also curious why you would want to include the Foo parent in equality for Bar since the Foo parent is not a member of Bar. I don't see a reason it breaks the equals contract but it seems unusual.

Comment: @Radiodef Totally agree. Just because the class is inner, the rules around hashCode and equals should not be broken.

Comment: The Foo instance is an implicit member of Bar. Via reflection, the field would be accessible.

Comment: I may be wrong about this but... You've got a line `// Will, of course, not compile.`, which seems to be trying to check whether the `Foo` elements are `equals()`. But the `.getClass()` part has already checked whether they are equal. In fact, it has checked an even more stringent condition: Each instance of `Foo` has a separate `Bar` class, so this can only be true if the `Foo`s are `==`. Do you require the `Foo`s to be `==`, or only `equals()`?

Comment: @DavidKnipe That's not true, Bar instances with different Foo parents will share the same class.

Comment: @Radiodef Because `Bar` is not static, it closes over all the state in its parent `Foo`, which is not that much different from that state being a members of `Bar`. Whenever you pass an instance of `Bar` around you are also passing the state of its parent `Foo` instance. Equality is a comparison of two instances' state, so I can see why you would want to do it.

Comment: @theon I disagree. The objective of the inner class is that it is closely tied to its parent and hence can access its private state. However, this does not equate to using the parent state to determine equality of the outer class.

Comment: It depends on the use case, but if I am an instance of `Bar` and my identity is defined by all the members of my `Foo` parent, then I can see how calling `Foo#equals` from `Bar#equals` would be useful. Because if two instances of `Bar` have only one field different in their parent, then they are not equal.

Comment: That basically is my use case. I use the inner class to create a type of member inheritence without wanting to expose the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. This is often done when you need to pass around "Key" objects that represent a unique identifier for some set of data but do not either have the data or want to transport it.

```
class SomeData {
    private String data;
    public static class Key {
        private final int firstId;
        private final int secondId; 

        public Key(int firstId, int secondId) {
            this.firstId = firstId;
            this.secondId = secondId;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object x) {
            if(!(x instanceof Key))
                return false;
            Key key = ((Key)x);

            return this.firstId == key.firstId 
            && this.secondId == key.secondId;

        }

        // implement hashCode as well
    }
}
```

In the example above the inner class is static but that doesn't really matter. The only reason I set it that way is so that exterior classes could construct it. Make sure when you are overriding the .equals that you also get the .hashCode. They should change with each other.

Comment: The identity of my inner class depends on my outer class's state.

Comment: Whether or not your inner classes state depends on your outer classes state really doesn't matter. The set of properties of your class that are defined in your equals are only limited by your requirements for scope. In other words there is no difference between my example and your requirement other than scope.